# How to tell openssl rsautl to use key stored in TPM?

Tags: linux, openssl, tpm

Is there any (easy) way to create a signature for a file using the command and the openssl rsautl command while the necessary key is stored in a TPM?

I just want to do the following with "key.pem" being a TPM-stored key.

```
openssl rsautl -sign -in file -inkey key.pem -out sig
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to tell openssl rsautl to use key stored in TPM?

OpenSSL does not provide an ENGINE for TPMs. I believe you need to use [TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/).

Dr. Henson made some comments about it on the OpenSSL mailing list at [TPM engine](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/TPM-engine-td28951.html).